# List containing functions is returned as None

Tags: python-3.x, return, nonetype

I have this simple function:

```
def double(x)   : return x*2
def triple(x)   : return x*3
def increment(x): return x+1

def find(n, moves=[]):
    if n == 1:
        print("Inside if statement with return")
        print("`moves` is not None: moves=", moves)
        return moves
    if n % 2 == 0:
        find(n // 2, moves + [double])
    elif n % 3 == 0:
        find(n // 3, moves + [triple])
    else:
        find(n - 1 , moves + [increment])


print("find has returned: ", find(23))
```

I expected a list of function as the return value but the actual output is:

```
Inside if statement with return
`moves` is not None: moves= [<function increment at 0x7f03e3944598>, <function double at 0x7f03e9f6cbf8>, <function increment at 0x7f03e3944598>, <function double at 0x7f03e9f6cbf8>, <function increment at 0x7f03e3944598>, <function double at 0x7f03e9f6cbf8>, <function double at 0x7f03e9f6cbf8>]
find has returned:  None
```

This is very unexpected as `moves` is not `None` inside the final `if` statement as shown by the print statement but None is returned.

Adding `[:]` after `return moves` changes nothing, `None` is still returned.

How can I `return` the actual contents of `moves`?

Comment: You do not `return` result of recursive `find` call.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski But why does the print print the correct value?

Comment: Hell, I was submiting an answer.

Comment: @Caridorc why shouldn't it? It is executed. `moves` is returned. And after that caller throws away (ignores) returned value, so final return value is `None` - all functions in Python implicitly returns `None`.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski Ok, it is clear now thanks